# How to create a circle imageview in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, imageview, geometry

I have a Recyclerview with images in it which I want to have in a Circle.
I've found CircleImageView.
github.com/jamesmontemagno/CircleImageView-Xamarin.Android

However, I can't get it working on my project. I've tried a blank project and it works there.
In my project I get the following message:

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML
>   file line #1: Error inflating class
>   refractored.controls.CircleImageView
>
> 01-09 10:51:13.374 D/Mono    (31872): Image addref
>   System.Runtime.Serialization[0xaa7856a0] ->
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.dll[0xa0d65e00]: 2 01-09 10:51:13.374
>   D/Mono    (31872): Prepared to set up assembly
>   'System.Runtime.Serialization' (System.Runtime.Serialization.dll)
>   01-09 10:51:13.374 D/Mono    (31872): Assembly
>   System.Runtime.Serialization[0xaa7856a0] added to domain RootDomain,
>   ref_count=1 01-09 10:51:13.374 D/Mono    (31872): AOT: image
>   'System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed:
>   library
>   "/data/app/DaringDuck.CommunityBuilder.Droid-1/lib/x86/libaot-System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so"
>   not found 01-09 10:51:13.375 D/Mono    (31872): AOT: image
>   '/usr/local/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so'
>   not found: dlopen failed: library
>   "/data/app/DaringDuck.CommunityBuilder.Droid-1/lib/x86/libaot-System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so"
>   not found 01-09 10:51:13.375 D/Mono    (31872): Config attempting to
>   parse: 'System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.config'. 01-09 10:51:13.375
>   D/Mono    (31872): Config attempting to parse:
>   '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Runtime.Serialization/System.Runtime.Serialization.config'.
>   01-09 10:51:13.375 D/Mono    (31872): Assembly Ref addref
>   Mono.Android[0x9ed54f00] -> System.Runtime.Serialization[0xaa7856a0]:
>   2 01-09 10:51:13.375 D/Mono    (31872): Assembly Ref addref
>   System.Runtime.Serialization[0xaa7856a0] -> mscorlib[0xaa785040]: 37

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/LLMain"
    android:background="#ffffff">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout_conm"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout9"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp">>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout10">
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="55dp"
                android:layout_height="55dp"
                android:id="@+id/ivAvatar"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/new_author" />
            <refractored.controls.CircleImageView  
                android:paddingTop="16dp" 
                android:layout_width="150dp" 
                android:layout_height="141.5dp"  
                android:id="@+id/navheader_userimage"  
                android:src="@drawable/icon"  
                app:civ_border_width="2dp"  
                app:civ_border_color="#000000" />
            <TextView
                android:text="Jared"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textAuthor"
                android:textColor="#313131"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:maxLength="8" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout11"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp">
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="85dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout12"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/momentImage"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Adapter

```
public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder
           OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).
                Inflate(Resource.Layout.MomentListItem, parent, false);
    MomentViewHolder vh = new MomentViewHolder(itemView);
    return vh;
}
```

Any idea's or suggestions?

Edit: added link

Comment: there is an Xamarin.Android bug in the latest version that causes the Java classes.zip to be fubar, try doing a clean/rebuild (delete the `obj` if needed to ensure a clean build) and what `Xamarin.Android` version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Xamarin 4.7.9.45, Xamarin.Android SDK 7.4.5.1.
I've tried what you recommended without luck.

Comment: I have installed the `Refractored.Controls.CircleImageView` nuget package and tested your code, I have some similar problem with my project. After deleting my bin and obj files and rebuild again, it works fine on my side.

Comment: Weird, I deleted the bin and obj folder by browsing to the .Droid folder. Then Rebuild, but I still experience the same problem.

Comment: Would you mind sharing a basic demo to reproduce this problem? that would be really appreciated!

Comment: In my project, I've tried to use it in About page which gives the same problem.

When I put the same AboutActivity with the same About.axml file in an empty project. It works. So strange, seems like something is wrong with my main project.

Comment: Can't find out why, struggling all day long. Is there any alternative?

Some extra info: 
https://hastebin.com/usemezuquz.http

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the documentations https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView ???

The name is `de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView`.
In your XML is `refractored.controls.CircleImageView`

which is exactly that the error you're getting is pointing to.

Comment: Im using xamarin, And have Read this: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CircleImageView-Xamarin.Android